# In SMIL, animate STROKE-WIDTH of all CIRCLES and LINES in same GROUP

Tags: svg-animate, smil

[Inkscape SVG](https://ky8d.net/bildoj/KY8D_Great_Circle_2250.svg)

Link is a map of locations from a web page. Note the location-dot (a CIRCLE) for Santa Fe New Mexico at 8 o'clock. See how it pulses. That is animating STROKE-WIDTH for that particular CIRCLE.

What I am wanting to do, is call that same animation for STROKE-WIDTH upon all objects in its same group. A single animation command which has effect across the entire group. So that all circles and lines grouped together shall pulse as one. And do it with a single command.

It happens in like that in Inkscape. I can select a group, and change an attribute, and said effect happens across the whole group. I am wanting to do that in SMIL.

Why? Because this map is to be of amateur radio contacts from a single antenna, but on different frequency bands. Right now it's static, and uses colors. But that is hideously busy. Also not clear. I want to make labels appear, like "160m", "80m", etc. ... and at the same time all those locations which correspond to that frequency will get fatter while the label is showing. Like that for a second. Then a new label shows, and its own set of locations show fatter. And so on.

But if I must evoke a separate animation for each circle, and not have it inherit that from the group, then it's too tedious, because each time I might add a new location, I'd have to write a separate animation for that. Rather I'd like to assign that new circle to a group, and have that be it.

Doable? If so, how? Please give example.

Thanks!

Gan Starling, KY8D

Answer (score 0):

As turns out, that's not possible. At least not wholly via SMIL.

I found I could do it instead via CSS, by embedding @keyframes rules.

I have modified the example to show this adjustment.